# I can't install lombok in Spring Tool Suite 4 ide on Ubuntu

Tags: java, lombok, sdkman, spring-tools-4

I'm trying to install lombok in the Spring Tool Suite 4 ide which is in the /opt folder on Ubuntu. The command: `java -jar lombok.jar` does not work because the opt folder requires privileges.
[image]

I tried using the command suggested by the installation software: `sudo java -jar lombok.jar` I get the result:

> sudo: java: command not found

Note: I have the SDKMAN software development kit manager installed to manage java versions.

Comment: (1) Easy way is: DO NOT PUT `sts-4.17.1.RELEASE` in `/opt` or use INSTALL, just download it , unzip, put it in your user folder like `~/TOOLS/sts-4.17.1.RELEASE` (2) And Why ? Because sdkman is under per user. root does not have sdkman or java. If you run `sudo java`, root does not have java.

Comment: In fact root doesn't have sdkman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because root does not have sdkman install. root can not get java.

You can do this:

```
sudo su -

mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm

cd /usr/lib/jvm

ln -s /home/YourUserName/.sdkman/candidates/java/current jdk

nano /root/.bashrc

# ADD This 
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk
export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk/bin:$PATH

# Ctrl + O save 
# Ctrl + X exit nano

exit
```

UPDATE:

Add JDK Path to sudoers config:

Run Command : `sudo nano /etc/sudoers`

find `Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sb..."`

append `:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk/bin` at end of this line

it will like `Defaults  secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk/bin"`

save and exit nano.

Test: `sudo java -version`

Then you can run `sudo java -jar lombok.jar`

Comment: 1. I don't own this folder: `/usr/lib/jvm`

 2. However, `/home/.bashrc` has the following configuration:

#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
`export SDKMAN_DIR="$HOME/.sdkman"
[[ -s "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"`

Comment: (1) `sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm` (2) config `/root/.bashrc` not your account `.bashrc` (root do not need install sdkman ) (3) add in /root/.bashrc is point to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk` (4) then `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk` the link is point to your `/home/YourUserName/.sdkman/candidates/java/current`

Comment: I couldn't, follow the steps in the terminal:

(1) clauber@clauber:~$ `sudo su -`

> [sudo] senha para clauber: 

(2) root@clauber:~# `mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm`

(3) root@clauber:~# `cd /usr/lib/jvm`

(4) root@clauber:/usr/lib/jvm# `ln -s /home/clauber/.sdkman/candidates/java/current jdk`

(5) root@clauber:/usr/lib/jvm# `nano /root/.bashrc`

(6) root@clauber:/usr/lib/jvm# `exit`

(7) clauber@clauber:~$ `sudo java -jar lombok.jar`

> sudo: java: command not found

Comment: run this , `sudo cat /root/.bashrc` , last two lines should be `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk
export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk/bin:$PATH`, no more

Comment: That's correct, I believe that the default java environment var settings must be different from sdkman.
I was able to install lombok with the default java install and then reinstall sdkman.

Comment: I am sorry, I update my answer, Find `UPDATE`, I add sudoers config.